# How to disable SSL-VPN on FortiOS 5.0

Tags: heartbleed, fortinet, fortigate

Hearbleed issue.
Must disable SSL-VPN.
I wasnt able to find it in the GUI.
Might there happen to be a CLI command?

Comment: They haven't issued a firmware update to fix?

Comment: They have. But Until I upgrade I must close the hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config vpn ssl settings
set sslvpn-enable disable
end
```

Cant believe no one knew of this...